# Does proxy setting affect the working of Azure bot?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, proxy, botframework

Symbols for Microsoft.Recognizer.Text.* and Microsoft.Recognizer.Definitions, taking time to load after removal of proxy.

I made a simple greeting bot using bot framework v4 using asp.net core. I'm working in an environment where proxy is set up. However, I've not connected it with Microsoft Azure yet. I'm just running it locally and testing it on emulator, so it has no internet requirements. Due to some other issue, I need to remove the proxy whenever I run the bot. But whenever I do so, symbols for Microsoft.Recognizer.Text.* and Microsoft.Recognizer.Definitions, take time to load, due to which there is a large time delay after every numeric, date, time input.

I'm a beginner to bot framework so please help me resolve this issue.

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft.Recognizer.Text.*, et al., is a dependency of Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs. If you're having difficulty loading it, try updating your nuget packages, or even doing a standalone installation of Microsoft.Recognizers.Text